# How to add permissions to windows named pipes using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, named-pipes

How can i add permissions for a specific group to read/write from an existent named pipe, using a powershell script?

This is as far as i went:

```
$AccessRule = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule( "Users", "FullControl", "Allow" )
$PipeSecurity = [System.IO.Directory]::GetAccessControl("\\.\pipe\docker_engine")
$PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
```

throw error

> Cannot convert argument "rule",
> with value: "System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule", for "AddAccessRule" to type
> "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule"

Answer (score 1):

```
$account="<DOMAIN>\<USERNAME>"
$npipe = "\\.\pipe\docker_engine"                                                                                 
$dInfo = New-Object "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" -ArgumentList $npipe                                               
$dSec = $dInfo.GetAccessControl()                                                                                 
$fullControl =[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl                                       
$allow =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow                                                  
$rule = New-Object "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule" -ArgumentList $account,$fullControl,$allow
$dSec.AddAccessRule($rule)                                                                                        
$dInfo.SetAccessControl($dSec)
```

Answer (score 1):

while Ben's solution does work, the access-rules are lost whenever the Docker deamon is restarted.

But there's a permanent fix permanent fix in case of Docker:
Create the file `%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json` with the following contents:

```
{
    "group": "Users"
}
```

This allows all users in the Windows group `Users` to open the named pipe without admin privileges.

Best
Jan

---

This is the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).

> -G, --group string | Group for the unix socket (default "docker")

It says "unix socket" but works for the named pipe too.

The default group seems to be `docker`, but is not created by the deamon. And Docker Desktop creates a group called `docker-users`.